# Girsanov kernel moments

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $Z_t=e^{\int_0^tq_tdB_t-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tq^2_tdt}$, where $(q_t)_{t\geq0}$ is a predictable process, and $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion. In particular, Novikov's condition ensures $\mathbb{E}[Z_t]=1$ and that $(Z_t)_{t\geq0}$ defines a measure $\mathbb{Q}$ equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$. The condition says that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tq^2_sds}]<\infty$.

This implies $\mathbb{E}[q_t^2]<\infty$, but what can be said about higher order moments? Assume $(q_t)_{t\geq0}$ to be positive. Is it easy to construct an example where $\mathbb{E}[q_t^k]=\infty$, or does Novikov's condition (or a similar condition) imply something "close" to $\mathbb{E}[q_t^k]=\infty,\;\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$?